# Multiple choices for a single case in the recursive formula of a Dynamic Programming algorithm

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming

I am developing a Dynamic Programming algorithm for a problem in scheduling. In the recursive formula, I have three cases: (1) $t_{i-1} = int$ (2) $t_{i-1}  = app \quad \& \quad r(j) \leq p $ and (3) $t_{i-1} = app \quad \& \quad r(j) > p$. However, for two of them I can go to two directions.

The formula is shown in the following, that is simplified to avoid misleading. In fact, cases 1 and 2 are the same, but can go into two directions ''app'' and ''int''. The same is for cases 3 and 4. But case 5 has only one option that is ''app''. I think the current format of the formula is missing something since the condition for cases 1 and 2, and for cases 3 and 4, is the same. What is the correct form of interpreting this formula?

\begin{equation}
z_i = \begin{cases}
z_{i-1} + p + (app) & \text{if $t_{i-1} = int$}\\
z_{i-1} + p+ (int) & \text{if $t_{i-1} = int$}\\
z_{i-1} + 2p + (app) & \text{if $t_{i-1} = app$} \quad \& \quad r(j) \leqslant p\\
z_{i-1} + 2p + (int) & \text{if $t_{i-1} = app$} \quad \& \quad r(j) \leqslant p\\
z_{i-1} + r(j) + (app) &\text{if $t_{i-1} = app$} \quad \& \quad r(j) > p \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Added:
One thing that comes to my mind is to write it with two $\min$ functions. Since from the three conditions with $(app)$ (i.e. conditions 1, 3 and 5) one with lower objective function will be remained, and the same for the two with $(int)$ option (i.e. conditions 2 and 4). How about writing with two $\min$ functions with distinct condition for each?! For example:
\begin{equation}
z_i = \begin{cases}
\min\begin{cases} z_{i-1} + p + (app) & \text{if $t_{i-1} = int$} \\ z_{i-1} + 2p + (app) & \text{if $t_{i-1} = app$} \quad \& \quad r(j) \leqslant p \\ z_{i-1} + r(j) + (app) &\text{if $t_{i-1} = app$} \quad \& \quad r(j) > p\end{cases} \\
\min\begin{cases}z_{i-1} + p+ (int) & \text{if $t_{i-1} = int$} \\
z_{i-1} + 2p + (int) & \text{if $t_{i-1} = app$} \quad \& \quad r(j) \leqslant p \end{cases}\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Comment: I don't understand this question. This does not look like a DP since it is not recursive. But in any case, it's not clear what you are asking. Are you saying that if $t_{i-1}=int$ then your formula says that $z$ should equal both $(app)$ and $(int)$? If so, I agree that seems like a problem, but you haven't provided enough information about what you _want_ $z$ to equal.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 Thanks. Yes, when $t_{i-1} = int$, then two options should be checked: $app$ and $int$. The same for cases 3 and 4. My question is that how I should present it in the formula, because in the current form the condition is the same, but we can have two answers for $z$.

Comment: What do you mean "two options should be checked"? Try explaining the rule in words: If $t_{i-1} = int$, then ... what should happen?

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 Suppose I have job $i-1$ scheduled. Then, if $t_{i-1} = int$, I can schedule the next job (job $i$) with two conditions: (1): start it immediately after job $i-1$ is finished, i.e. at point $C_{i-1}$ or (2): start it two time slots earlier than job $i-1$ is finished, i.e. at $C_{i-1}-2$. Both directions should be checked in the DP.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's cleanest if you think about formulating your DP something like this:

$$z_i = \min_{a\in A(t_{i-1})} \{f_i(a)\},$$

where

- $A(t_{i-1})$ is the set of available actions you can take, given the value of $t_{i-1}$, that is:

$$A(t_{i-1}) = \begin{cases} \{C_{i-1}, C_{i-1}-2\}, & \text{if } t_{i-1}=int, \\
  \{C_{i-1}\}, & \text{if } t_{i-1}=app,\end{cases}$$
or something like that.

- $f_i(a)$ is the cost/reward function value if you take action $a$ for job $i$. You haven't said what your objective function is, and I don't know what $p$ or $r(j)$ are, but presumably those can be incorporated into $f_i(a)$.

I'm sure I'm getting some of the notation and concepts wrong, but in general I suggest that you distinguish between the *state* ($t_{i-1}$), the *actions* ($C_{i-1}-2$, etc.), and the *costs/rewards* ($f_i(a)$).